# Can you track an individual purchase through SkyScanner's Travel API?

Tags: api, skyscanner

I'm looking to integrate SkyScanner's Travel API on to my site and I was wondering if one is able to track when the user has completed the booking and how much they spent during that session.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer... it's not possible. I guess mainly because of privacy issues.